# Android Random Thread Error

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I'm getting an odd error in my Android game. Whenever I try to change level (exit one activity and start another, and then reenter the first one) I get this error in 1/10 cases, which is really odd.

In addition to that, I'm very bad at understanding error, like this one:

```
08-05 21:07:19.512: W/dalvikvm(29961): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d1b2a0)
08-05 21:07:19.520: E/AndroidRuntime(29961): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1423
08-05 21:07:19.520: E/AndroidRuntime(29961): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 21:07:19.520: E/AndroidRuntime(29961):    at com.coderogden.pongtennis.views.MultiGameView.outOfBounds(MultiGameView.java:360)
```

What does it mean and how do I solve it?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT

This is line 360

```
if (ball.getY() + ball.getRadius() > box.getBoxBot()) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a quite typical `NullPointerException`. Start your diagnostic by going to the line 360 of your `MultiGameView.java` file and looking for a variable which is used at that line, but may sometimes be `null`. There is little more to add based on your input.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I couldn't solve the error, but I do at least know why I'm getting it right now. I have sound effects in my game, and if I exit a level while a sound effect is on (0,5s-1.5s long) I get this error. When I debugged the app I tested all levels really quick by exiting as fast as possible, which caused the error.